# js write nested json object

Tags: javascript, jquery, arrays, json

I've that data:

```
var data = {
            resultDescription: "SUCCESS",
            data: [ ["JAN","1048729"], ["FEB","1220608"],["MAR","1299965"],["APR","1288644"],["MAY","1077342"],["JUN","705690"],["JUL","666131"],["AUG","769444"],["SEP","581618"],["OCT","564438"],["NOV","535066"],["DEC","1241228"]]};
```

and I'm trying to convert it into json which chart will accept. For that I've divided it's data to 2 1d array:

```
for(var i = 0; i < data.data.length; i++)
{
    newArr = newArr.concat(data.data[i]);
}



for(var i=0; i< newArr.length; i++){
    if(i%2==0){
        labelsArr = labelsArr.concat(newArr[i]);
    }
    else{
        dataArr = dataArr.concat(newArr[i]);
    }
}


            var mappedData = data.data.map(function(item) { 
                return {labels: labelsArr, data: dataArr};
            });
```

[**JSFIDDLE FOR FULL EXAMPLE**](http://jsfiddle.net/r3k38d3j/5/)

but it gives me that json format:

> data: Array[12]
>
> labels: Array[12]

but I want

> ```
> labels: Array[12],
> datasets: [{
> data: Array[12]
> }]
> ```

How can I achieve that?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Change your `return` statement as follows

```
return { labels: labelsArr, datasets: [ {data : dataArr} ] };
```